# How to grep special characters, "^A", ^[, ^[[

Tags: grep, zsh

I know how to output bindkeys using `bindkey`.

I can `grep` a word.

```
$ bindkey | grep line
"^A" beginning-of-line
"^E" end-of-line
"^J" accept-line
"^K" kill-line
...
```

But I can't grep `^[G` or `^[[A`, etc.

```
$ bindkey | grep ^[G
zsh: bad pattern: ^[G
```

How can I `grep` by keywords like `^[G` or `^[[A`, etc?

Answer (score 2):

Two problems: characters that are special to the shell, and characters that are special in regexes.

The open bracket `[` has a special meaning in the shell's filename expansion patterns, which is what zsh refers to with that error. You can tell it to take the characters literally with quotes. Either single or double quotes should do, but single quotes are better, they have less exceptions.

In regexes, an initial `^` tells to anchor the pattern to start of line, and `[` has a special meaning similar to the one it has in the shell. So you need to tell `grep` to treat both of them as literals, this is done by escaping them with backslashes.

So:

```
bindkey | grep '\^\[G'
```

Note that the `^A` in the output of `bindkey` is the two characters `^` (caret) and `A` (uppercase letter A), while what that combination stands for in the key bindings is Ctrl-A, the control character with numerical value 1. Grepping for that character would be different.

Comment: `^` is also an `extendedglob` operator in `zsh`. See also `bindkey '^[F'` or  Alt+X, then `descr<Tab>` which expands to `describe-key-briefly`, and then type the key or key sequence you want described.

Answer (score 2):

Using `-F` option and using quotes worked.

```
~ % bindkey | grep -F '^[G'
"^[G" get-line
```

> -F, --fixed-strings Interpret PATTERN as a list of fixed strings, separated by newlines, any of which is to be matched. (-F is specified
> by POSIX .)

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to get a control character, use hexcodes. E.g. a TAB:

```
grep -P '\x09'
```

Alternatively

```
grep -P '\t'
```

Find a list [here](https://unicode-table.com/en/).